# Why isn't a tuple that contains two empty list an empty tuple?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

I have a script that basically returns a tuple from a function:

```
results = some_function()
```

Then I'm checking to see if there are any results like so:

```
if results:
   do_something()
```

This returns `True` when the tuple has two empty lists.  When I use debug mode my `results` are `([], [])`.  Running `len(results)` produces a length of `2`.

Interestingly, if I do the following:

```
results = ([])
print(len(results))
```

It prints `0`.  Why is that adding another list prints `2`?

Should I be overriding the class method `__len__` from the function producing the tuple?

Comment: `([])` is _not a tuple at all_, it is an empty list written with parens around it. If you want a single-element tuple, add a comma: `([],)`.

Comment: @free_mind That is *the* dupe canonical for such posts. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/12876177. Anyway, Closing as a dupe implies that your question is a good signpost for future readers to view the main question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tuple is defined by the comma, not the parentheses:

```
>>> results = ([],)
>>> print(len(results))
1
```

Comment: absolutely the right answer. `([])`is not the same as `([],)` +1

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I didn't know this.